# Image not visible from Back-end

Tags: magento-1.9, image-preview

When i upload images, its fine to look frond end, but it does not appear in the backend.

[image]

Comment: Permission issue at media folder

Comment: how can i solve this

Comment: give permission  `644` recursively at media folder and `755` for files,please check the link  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12158/what-permissions-should-i-give-var-and-media

Comment: is this right      http://i.imgur.com/XsZR661.png

Answer (score 0):

The below I feel is a good compromise for convenience vs lock down.
Log in to your server over SSH and use the following command for changing the permission on your media folder:

```
chmod -Rf 777 media
```

Comment: is this right,   http://i.imgur.com/XsZR661.png

Comment: Should be yes, can you check if it works?

Comment: no, its not working

Comment: any other changes can i made

Comment: Did you flush the cache?

Comment: @ Klettseb : am solved error, because of i have installed jpeg/png compression, after i deleted error solved, Actually jpeg/png compression not support my theme.

Comment: Ok great ! So the permissions were set correctly :-)

Comment: Maybe post your answer and accept it as then your question is closed