# Internal Server Error (500) in ُshow site photo

Tags: magento-1.9.2.0

I uploaded all the files to the server but the site's photos are not showing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to reset permission of your media folder and files using below commands-

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

for further info check this link > [What permissions should I give /var and /media?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12158/what-permissions-should-i-give-var-and-media)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an internal server error you should also check the apache error logs for any information on the error.
They usualy reside in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Though depending on your server/provider it might be different.